# ¿Por qué no me deja agregar "foreign key"?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE horario;

USE horario;

CREATE TABLE semana (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  nombre char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  totales char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  extras char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)

CREATE TABLE dia(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
numSemana int(11) NOT NULL,
nombreSemana char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
dia int(1) NOT NULL,
horas char(6) NOT NULL default '',
extra char(6) NOT NULL default '',
entrada char(6) NOT NULL default '',
salida char(6) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (numSemana) REFERENCES semana (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
;


ALTER TABLE dia
ADD FOREIGN KEY(nombreSemana) REFERENCES semana(nombre);
```

Comment: Te invito a visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga una mejor calidad y obtengas una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Y qué error te sale al ejecutar este código? Por favor añade los mensajes de error que encuentras editando tu pregunta.

Comment: me parece que el error radica en que tratas de usar como llaves foráneas campos que no son llaves primarias si no que solo estan declarados como char

Answer (score 4):

[La documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) dice lo siguiente:

> NDB requires an explicit unique key (or primary key) on any column
> referenced as a foreign key.
>
> ---
>
> NDB requiere una clave única explícita (o clave principal) en cualquier columna a la que se haga referencia como clave externa.

Esta restricción no se cumple con tu columna `nombre`  de la tabla `semana`.

Si por ejemplo tú indicas que esa columna tendrá un índice del tipo `UNIQUE` verás que será posible crear las relaciones sin problemas.

```
CREATE TABLE `semana` 
(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `nombre` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `totales` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `extras` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX `idx_nombre`(`nombre`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `dia`  
(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `numSemana` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    `nombreSemana` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `dia` INT(1) NOT NULL, 
    `horas` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `extra` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `entrada` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    `salida` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
    FOREIGN KEY (`numSemana`) REFERENCES `semana` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE `dia` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY(`nombreSemana`) 
REFERENCES `semana`(`nombre`);
```