# DUDAS CLAVE FORANEA AL RELACIONAR CON EL CAMPO DE OTRA TABLA

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando una BD en MYSQL WORKBENCH mediante ER, la cuestión es que quiero que la clave foránea de la tabla CLIENTE sea clave primaria de la tabla SERVICIOS, al momento de relacionarlas me tira un error, el cual me dice que debo tener las dos bajo el mismo tipo de datos.

Para ser más especifico deseo, que SERVICIOS_CLI INT de la tabla CLIENTE sea la clave primaria de SERVICIOS.
adjunto el diagrama ER y el error que me tira.
Soy nuevo en esto :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quiere decir el mensaje de error es que `SERVICIOS_CLI` debe ser del mismo tipo en ambas tablas (eso está OK porque en ambas es del tipo `INT`)  y que debe estar indexada en la tabla referenciada. Ya que la tabla tiene una llave primaria, entonces, `SERVICIOS_CLI` podría ser `UNIQUE` por ejemplo. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161087/29967) donde se trata un problema parecido al tuyo.

Comment: en tu primera imagen tienes claves primarias (necesarias para identificar inequívocamente cada registro) en las tablas CLIENTE y SERVICIOS, pero en la segunda imagen solo tienes una clave foránea en la tabla SERVICIOS, la tabla SERVICIOS debe tener tanto una clave primaria como una clave foránea (a no ser que sea una entidad debil, pero no creo que sea el caso), asegúrate de tener la clave primaria de SERVICIOS (int, auto incrementable y no nula)